# Toggle navbar icon on click for small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to coding. I am unable to create a navbar icon that changes on small screen when it is clicked.

I have tried using a bootstrap navbar, when I click the navbar on small screen, it only shows the navbar list but the icon doesn't change.
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoWrr.jpg)

I expect to have the navbar icon to change when clicked on small screen as in the image below.
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjvZ5.jpg)

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Office <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Windows<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Xbox<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">All Microsoft</a
            >

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need help with this, I am new to Dev and Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a default behavior of bootstrap navbar. Add cross icon in your html code near the `navbar-toggler-icon`

For example:

```
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
<span class="navbar-close-icon">X</span>
```

Add some styles for it:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-close-icon {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed .navbar-close-icon {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed .navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And add class `collapsed` for `<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right">` by default

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
    .navbar-toggler-icon {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar-close-icon {
      display:inline-block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-toggler.collapsed .navbar-close-icon {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggler.collapsed .navbar-toggler-icon {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler collapsed"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <span class="navbar-close-icon">X</span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Office <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Windows<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Xbox<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              id="navbarDropdown"
              role="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
              >All Microsoft</a
            >

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="user"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="user"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="user"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the navbar icon when it is clicked on small screen, you can add some JavaScript to toggle a class on the navbar-toggler-icon element.

```js
<script>
  var navbarTogglerIcon = document.getElementById("navbar-toggler-icon");
  navbarTogglerIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    navbarTogglerIcon.classList.toggle("close");
  });
</script>
```

```css
.navbar-toggler-icon.close {
  background-image: url('close-icon.png');
  /* add any other styles you want */
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span id="navbar-toggler-icon" class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by default in Bootstrap 4. You will have to write some additional CSS to display the respective icons when the `.navbar-toggler` is or isn't `.collapsed`.

```css
.close {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.close {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    <span class="close px-2 py-1">X</span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Office <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Windows<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Xbox<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">All Microsoft</a
            >

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```